# why isnt this pause menu code working?

Tags: unity, c#

the code when it works right should pause the game (which means setting the timescale to 0)when you press esc and bring up a pause menu. it does this, but when i press the menu button( which brings me to the main menu) and then press play(brings me to level 1) the level starts off with a timescale of 0 and i have to press esc for the game to start.

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;

    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    void Start()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }
    public void Resume()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }

    void Pause()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }

    public void LoadMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("main menu");
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Where do you set time scale back to 1 when returning to the main menu?

Comment: oh I didn't know I needed to I thought it was just for one scene(I'm new to coding and unity) but I guess it was frozen in the main menu too I just couldn't tell. what sort of code would that be?

Comment: figured it out thanks

Comment: Want to post your solution as an Answer below?

Comment: yeah sorry ill do that from now on

Answer (score 1):

just put the timescale set to 1 under the public void load menu.

```
 public void LoadMenu()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("main menu");
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}
```

Comment: Remember to mark this answer as Accepted if it worked for you.